# Division by zero, php

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

I have created this function that correctly displays the infinity symbol when trying to enter 0 into the Y text box. However I still get the division by zero error... here is my code.

here is the case for switch statment

```
case '/':             
    $prod = $x / $y;     
    break;
```

hh

```
//check for divide by 0
function check0($y)
{
    if ($y == 0)
        throw new Exception ($prod = "&#8734");

    return FALSE;
 }

 try
 {
    check0($y);
    $prod = $x /$y;   
 }catch(Exception $zero){
     echo $zero->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: how is the code actually organized? I see a divide and then a `break` (no call to `check0` at the top.

Comment: What's this line $prod = $x / $y; before the break? Is it surrounded by a try{...}catch{...} ?

Comment: The current answer covers it, but some additional notes: why is there an assignment inside the Exception constructor? Also, you shouldn't be using an exception for control flow. Just use an if statement to return the infinity sign instead of doing the division.

Comment: can you post the error that you get? there should be a line number in the error which should give you a hint what you have wrong

Comment: What if $x is negative? Negative infinity is a possibility too...

Answer (score 2):

**First**: you are doing a division at the second line code (which can be devision by zero).

**Second**: no need to return false in your method since you are throwing an error.

**Third**: Why using an exception here and not just let you method return true of false and check on that before executing the devision.

**Fourth**: Why having a method if you only need to check on the value of $y. Calling the method or including an if-statement requires both just one line of code.

So, why can't it just be like:

```
case '/':                  
    if($y > 0)
        $prod = $x / $y;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you actually do the division near the top (in the `case`).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic feels ... mmm well entangled.... Here have a look at this:

```
<?php
    function divide($x, $y) {
        if ( $y === 0 ) 
            throw new Exception("Divide By Zero");
        return $x/$y;
    }

    try {
        $product = divide(3, 0);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        if ( $e->getMessage() == "Divide By Zero" ) 
            $product = "&#8734";
        else
            $product = NULL;
    }
    print "Product is $product\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything works fine. Be sure, you are not trying to use division earlier in your script, because it look's like.

```
case '/':
$prod = $x / $y;
break;
```

starts before your function call.

Answer (score 0):

You must call check0() before division. You should return FALSE if y == 0, TRUE otherwise.
If return TRUE then do division. However it's not necessary call a method to do this!